# Resume web service method when app is launching again

Tags: ios

I am developing an iOS application in which I am updating my database content from a web service.

But when the user kills the application and starts it again then I want to resume my web service method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I think , you want to update your database As you application launches again.

Then you can use
 `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Of AppDelegate

which is called every time an application launches.
If you want it for some specific viewController you can add the method in viewWillAppear block

Comment: Actually before application is killed I have to save that how much part of database has been updated  and when we launch app again then i have to start from rest of the data

Comment: so plz provide help me for this scenario

Comment: - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
handles the kill process, but i will recommend you to use viewWillDisappear or someother method where you want to save the database, And initialise it when app launches

Comment: thanks .I was using - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application but when i kill the application and if we write any code in - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application them application get crashed.I am confused that viewWillDisappear is avaalable in app delegate or not

Comment: You cant plan the crashing of an app thats why I suggested you to save your data on regular basis, which is a much better approach .

Comment: plz tell me method in app delegate which is bestin this scenario       thanks a lot i think my problem is solved

Comment: if your problem is solved , then mark it as an answer so that it can help other users too :D